# Splitting paragraphs into different divs

Tags: php, jquery, flexbox

I am getting paragraphs from the database as arrays, for example

```
<?php $data = [
     "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
     "It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
     "The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham."
  ];?>
```

and I am printing the paragraphs into columns using css and html as newspaper and theres no scroll in the page, if theres extra text it should be in the second page.

so for example this should be rendered into this

```
<div id="page-1">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
    <p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div id="page-2">
    <p>de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
</div>
```

The problem I am having is I cant figure out how to know when to split to the second page, I tried to count the words or paragraphs but I don't think it's a good solution.

Any help please

Comment: If each array value is considered a column like your example, I would probably `array_chunk()` with a split value of `2`, then loop the chunks.

Comment: You can't do this using PHP since PHP runs on the server and has no clue about how much info fits on one page (which I'm assuming differs depending on the clients browser size and such?)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried string escape such that when the code encounters a specific character (such as a full stop), it ends the paragraph and creates a new one.

```
preg_replace('/\./', '/</p><p>', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate each words into single element to compute width and height to fit into container. Please see comments in the codes for explanations.

Demo here:
https://paiza.io/projects/e/E5YUotJG0ilsaH8ZI-bH1g?theme=twilight

Whole Code:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.",
    "It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.",
    "The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from 'de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum' by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham."
    );
// add newline indicators
$str = implode("{{nl}} ", $data);
// separate all spaces into divs
$str = "<div class='ib txt'>". str_replace(" ", "</div><div class='ib txt'>", $str) ."</div>";
// add additional indicator for end characters of paragraph
$str = preg_replace("/<div class='ib txt'>([^<]*)\{\{nl\}\}<\/div>/", "<div class='ib txt greedwidth'>$1</div>", $str);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #container {
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }
        .txt {
            /*border: 1px solid #ccc;*/ /* uncomment to show guidelines */ 
            padding: 5px 10px;
        }
        .ib {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        #all_content {
            display: block; 
            visibility: hidden; 
            position:absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="all_content"><?=$str;?></div>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <div>
        <button id="back_page" onclick="show_page(0)"> << </button>
        <button id="next_page" onclick="show_page(0)"> >> </button>
    </div>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var elements = [];

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var page_width_limit = $('#container').innerWidth();
            // fix height based on first div - given all texts have same height
            var page_height_limit = Math.floor($('#container').innerHeight()/$('#all_content div.txt:first').outerHeight()) * $('#all_content div.txt:first').outerHeight();
            var page_limit = page_width_limit * page_height_limit;

            var cur_dimension = 0;
            var width_padding = 0;

            $('#all_content div').each(function() {

                // padding width
                width_padding += $(this).outerWidth();
                let additional_width = 0;
                if (width_padding > page_width_limit) {
                    additional_width = page_width_limit - (width_padding - $(this).outerWidth());
                    width_padding = $(this).outerWidth();
                }

                // greedy width
                if ($(this).hasClass('greedwidth')) {
                    let _tmp_orig_width = $(this).outerWidth();
                    $(this).outerWidth(page_width_limit - (width_padding - $(this).outerWidth())-1);
                    width_padding += ($(this).outerWidth() - _tmp_orig_width);
                }

                // store elements on their respective page
                cur_dimension += ($(this).outerWidth() + additional_width) * $(this).outerHeight();
                let index = Math.floor(cur_dimension/page_limit);
                if (typeof elements[index] === 'undefined') {
                    elements[index] = [];
                } 
                elements[index].push(this);
            });

            // show first page
            show_page(0);
        });

        function show_page(page) {
            if (typeof elements[page] === 'undefined') 
                return false;

            // navigator
            $("#back_page").attr('onclick', "show_page("+ (page-1) +")");
            $("#next_page").attr('onclick', "show_page("+ (page+1) +")");

            // display page
            $('#container').html("");
            for (var elem of elements[page]) {
                $('#container').append(elem);
            }

            return true;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```